# can I assign multiple $watchCollection programmaticaly?

Tags: angularjs

Imagine that I have an array called `buckets`. that array will contain objects called `bucket` where each `bucket` has a property called `images` which is an array. Example:

```
vm.buckets = [
    {name: "bucket1", images: []},
    {name: "bucket2", images: []},
    {name: "bucket3", images: []}
]
```

I am dynamically adding new buckets to `vm.buckets` , but also dynamically adding new images to each bucket. Is there a way to create a new `$watchCollection` and assign it to every new bucket so that i can watch for new images being inserted into each bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.buckets = [
    { name: "bucket1", images: [] },
    { name: "bucket2", images: [] },
    { name: "bucket3", images: [] }    
  ];
  var counter = vm.buckets.length;
  
  vm.Addbucket = function() {
    var temp = {
      name: 'bucket' + (++counter),
      images: []
    };
    vm.buckets.push(temp);
    AddWatch(temp);
  }
  vm.DeleteLastBucket = function(){
    vm.buckets[vm.buckets.length - 1].unregisterWatch();
    vm.buckets.splice(vm.buckets.length - 1, 1);
  }

  function AddWatch(x) {
    var index = vm.buckets.indexOf(x);
    var id = `buckets[${index}].images`;    
    x.unregisterWatch = $scope.$watchCollection(id, function() {
      console.log(`Changes at ${x.name} images`);
    });    
  }

  $scope.buckets = vm.buckets;
  vm.buckets.forEach(AddWatch);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl as vm'>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='item in vm.buckets'>
      {{item.name}}: {{item.images.length}} images
      <button ng-click='item.images.push("temp")'>Add image</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-click='vm.Addbucket()'>Add bucket</button>
  <button ng-click='vm.DeleteLastBucket()'>Delete last bucket</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds great. What happens when the bucket object is deleted? Do I need to unsubscribe from the $watchCollection?

Comment: @konrad, I think, it is not very necessary, but you can do that by calling `unregisterWatch` function, which is returned as a result of `$watchCollection`.